# How can I avoid re-rendering of component due to props change, to fix performance problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native, redux

I have a component, where on submit a form. I am cleaning up redux values.

```js
submitForm.then(() => {
            setUserAssignModal(false);
            updateUserTrack({
              counterOrdersCount: trackUserVisit.counterOrdersCount + 1
            });
            handleOrderSubmit(userOrdersData);
            if (appliedDiscount) {
              this.handleRemoveDiscount();
            }

            setMoreOrderInfo({
              isPackingIncluded: false,
              userName: "",
              userPhone: "",
              selectedPaymentType: {
                id: null,
                mode: null
              }
            });
            navigation.navigate("Order");
```

so, before navigating, my component props are changing, its re-rendering nearly 10 times. 
How can I perform cleanup actions after navigating current screen to orders screen, to avoid unnecessary  re-renders?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have so many pieces of state that are being updated in one block of code which causes the unnecessary re-renders. You have to keep your state in one object so that you can clean all at once as passing a default/initial state to it. If you are already using Redux, your reducer might do the job just fine. If your state pieces are local, then you might try getting them all in one object so that way you can have fewer re-renders.